# Как в NestJS сделать регистрацию пользователя в Keycloak через Google OAuth?

Tags: javascript, nestjs, keycloak, google-oauth2

У меня есть сервер на NestJS, мне надо, чтобы пользователь зарегистрировался в Keycloak, используя Google. Как это можно реализовать? Google Api уже сделал.

Делал через `PassportStrategy`, но получая данные, не могу закинуть пользователя в систему, так как пароля нет, чтобы зарегистрировать через `create()`. Настраивал `Identity Provider` в Keycloak, но кнопка появляется в самой панели Keycloak, и если вставить в `PassportStrategy` в `callbackURL` ссылку на IDP Google redirect url, то выдает ошибку, так как требует `client-id` (не гугловский).

Возможно, надо сделать клиент, но не знаю, какие настройки для этого поставить и какой запрос полностью писать. Вот ответ с Keycloak, когда пытался до этого:

```
2023-07-03 18:22:51 2023-07-03 15:22:51,862 WARN  [org.keycloak.events]
(executor-thread-59) type=IDENTITY_PROVIDER_LOGIN_ERROR, 
realmId=7806201d-8bd3-48f3-809c-03a2dc2d1c93, clientId=null, 
userId=null, ipAddress=172.18.0.1, 
error=identity_provider_login_failure
```

C Keycloak работать начал совсем недавно, спасибо за помощь!